# Volume of solid bounded by surfaces

Tags: integration, surfaces

Find the volume of the solid bounded by these two surfaces:
$$
\text{surface a: }z=x^2+y^2\\
\text{surface b: }z=1-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$
Can someone please help me out? Should I use cylindrical or spherical? I've already tried both and can't find the correct answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cylindrical is the way to go (spherical will work, but when no spheres or expressions using $x^2+y^2+z^2$ appear, it's best to avoid them since they have messier formulae for things like $dV$ and $dS$). Here, we have no $x$ or $y$ separately, but $x^2+y^2$, which is a good hint to use cylindricals.

In cylindricals, the surfaces are
$$ z = r^2, \qquad z=1-r. $$
First question: when do these intersect? When $r^2=z=1-r$, so $r^2+r-1=0$, or $r=\frac{-1 + \sqrt{1+4}}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ (the other root is negative, so meaningless since $r \geq 0$). Let's call this $a$ for short.

So the integral is over the region $r^2 < z < 1-r$, where $0<r<a$. $dV=r \, dr\, d\theta \, dz$ has no $z$-dependence, so we may as well do the $z$ integral first. Thus the volume is
$$ V=\int_{r=0}^a \int_{z=r^2}^{1-r} \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} r \, d\theta \, dz \, dr. $$
This is simple enough: the inner integral gives $2\pi$. The $z$ integral gives $1-r-r^2$, so we have
$$ V= 2\pi \int_{r=0}^a (1-r-r^2)r \, dr = 2\pi \left[ \frac{r^2}{2}-\frac{r^3}{3} - \frac{r^4}{4} \right]_0^a = \frac{a^2}{6}(6-4a - 3a^2 )\pi $$
Thankfully we know that $a^2=1-a$, so we can simplify this so we don't have to square $a$ directly:
$$ \frac{a^2}{6}(6-4a - 3a^2 )\pi = \frac{1-a}{6}(6-4a - 3(1-a) )\pi \\
= \frac{(1-a)(3-a)}{6}\pi = \frac{3-4a+a^2}{6}\pi = \frac{4-5a}{6}\pi = \frac{13-5\sqrt{5}}{12}\pi $$

Comment: Perfect. I did everything you've done until $a^2 = 1-a$, and then I messed everything... Why is that true?

Comment: $a$ is the value of $r$ where the two surfaces meet, so $a^2 = z = 1-a $ (where $z$ is the value of $z$ where the intersection occurs). $a$ is chosen to be the positive solution of this equation, so it must satisfy it.

Comment: Now I see it. Thanks!

Comment: Moral of the story: algebra is hard to get right. I made a mess of the algebra in that last displayed set of equations the first time I did it, and I knew that was *easier* than trying to square the actual value of $a$ and multiply it by itself to other powers and so on. But it was much easier to find the error than it would have been with more numbers flying around!

Comment: you are totally right. I'm so inattentive that almost every time I get the right reasoning, but always fail in some algebra... It wasn't different this time! Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Using cylindrical polars $(r, \theta, z)$, we have the surfaces $S_a$ and $S_b$ given by $$S_a = \lbrace (r, \theta, z) : z = r^2 \rbrace$$
and
$$S_b = \lbrace (r, \theta, z) : z = 1 - r \rbrace$$

Note in the region we want, $r^2 \leq 1-r$, so noting that $r^2 = 1-r \implies r = r_+ = \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$, we have $r \in [0, r_+]$.

Hence the volume is given by
$$V = \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^{r_+} \int_{r^2}^{1-r} r \; \mathrm{d}z \, \mathrm{d}r \,\mathrm{d}\theta = 2 \pi \int_0^{r_+} (1-r)r-r^3 \mathrm{d}r = 2 \pi \left[ -\frac{r^4}{4} - \frac{r^3}{3} + \frac{r^2}{2} \right]_0^{r_+} = \frac{\pi}{6} r_+^2 \left( 6 - 4r_+ - 3r_+^2\right) = \frac{\pi}{12} \left(13 - 5\sqrt{5}\right) \approx 0.476$$